# ANGULAR: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Angular error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, eventos

Buenos días estoy haciendo un proyecto de una app de recetas y me da el siguiente error: 'Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Estoy simplemente programando la navegación, mediante funciones y databinding, al ser un EventEmitter tengo que pasarle los datos a la función que emite, por lo que debería ser con $event para que comprenda que se pasan los datos de una u otra.

¿Alguien sabe por que me da este error?
Es un ejercicio de un curso y está completamente igual a como se enseña en el curso, pero el ejemplo del curso sale bien, alguna ayuda?

No me gustaría hacerlo diferente, ni mejorarlo ni nada, simplemente saber y comprender porque me da este error en la linea <app-header (featureSelected)="onNavigate($event)">
Gracias de antemano

App component.html

```
 <app-header (featureSelected)="onNavigate($event)"></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes *ngIf="loadedFeature==='recipe'"></app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list *ngIf="loadedFeature==='shopping-list'"></app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

App component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'recetas';
      loadedFeature='recipe';
      
      onNavigate(feature:string){
        this.loadedFeature=feature;
      }
    }
```

Header component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('recipe')">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect('shopping-list')">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Save data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Header component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl:'header.component.html',
    styleUrls:['header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent{
    @Output() featuredSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

    onSelect(feature:string){
        this.featuredSelected.emit(feature);
        }
}
```

---

El problema se soluciono debugeandolo con un alias en el @Output, y era porque no tenía bien escrito el nombre de la función al pasarlo en el <app-header feature**d**Selected=""> me faltaba una D en feature,y funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

En el app.component.html `(featureSelected)="onNavigate($event)"` le estás pasando un objeto de tipo Event a la función `onNavigate`, en cambio en el app.component.ts recibes un tipo string en la funcion

```
onNavigate(feature:string){ 
    this.loadedFeature=feature;
}
```

Para que funcione coloca

```
onNavigate(feature: any){
    console.log(feature);
}
```

En el navegador checas cual es exactamente el tipo de dato que le envias y lo colacas en el parametro que recibe la función.

Espero haberte ayudado.